# VBA: Pull specific row data

Tags: vba, excel

I have my excel sheet data(i converted into array format) which looks like following

```
1st row......['one', , , , 'Folder', 'Folder', 'Extended Data', 'Extended Data', 'Extended Data','Extended Data' ],
2nd row.....['ID', 'Label', 'Longitude', 'Latitude', 'Country', 'City', 'Inventory', 'Safety stock', 'weight', 'hdsjka'],
3rd row......['AFKBL', 'Kabul, Afghanistan', 69.136749, 34.53091, 'Afghanistan', 'Kabul', 12, 1845, 12, 1845],
4th row......['AFKDH', 'Kandahar, Afghanistan', 65.700279, 31.61087, 'Afghanistan', 'Kandahar', 18, 1193, 18, 1193], ....etc etc
```

I want to pull all the values in the 2nd row that comes under 'Extended Data' ( which is in 1st row)
 and write it into a single column array in a different file..

I want to use this column array for creating a control wrapper in google charts.

I would really appreciate if anybody could write a macro and help me on this..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't quite make out how what your array looks like, but it seems to me that the data you want should be simple to obtain by looping across the array cells. 
  Say the data you want is in row 2 and columns 4 to 7 of the array you already have ("oldarr"), then you just create a new array of newarr(4,1).

```
dim newarr(4,1)
for j = 1 to 4
newarr(j,1) = arr(2, (j+3)) ''cycles across the needed columns on the second row 
next j
```

You can then paste the contents of newarr wherever you like.

Now, this seems much too simple to require a macro to do, which is why I think I have to be missing something. However, the general approach holds as long as you know which array columns will contain the information you want.  The only subtleties I could think of would be if you don't know how many rows or columns you need to copy in each iteration (in which case you could use a dynamic array), or if the columns containing "Extended Data" can change.

Hope this can at least help you get started.

Comment: Thanks for your response.your guess was right.. I don't know how many columns I am going to have under "extended data". I will try to work on this..